# listNode public method not accessing private data member

Tags: java, methods, private, public

I'm working on a linked list assignment for some homework and I'm having some trouble getting my ListNode class to work. Every time I compile I get this error.

```
C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\java\ListPkg\ListNode.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    node = next;
    ^
  symbol:   variable node
  location: class ListNode<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class ListNode
1 error
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
```

Here is the code. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, its probably an easy fix that I'm missing.

```
package ListPkg;

public class ListNode<T extends Comparable <T>>
{

private T data;
private ListNode<T> nextNode;

public ListNode(T object)
{
    setData(object);
    setNext(null);
}

public ListNode(T object, ListNode<T> node)
{
    setData(object);
    setNext(node);
}

public void setData(T object)
{
    data = object;
}

public T getData()
{
    return data;
}

public void setNext(ListNode<T> next)
{
    node = next;
}

public ListNode<T> getNext()
{
    return nextNode;
}
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I feel like an idiot, that was supposed to be nextNode. Fixed that and its compiling. Thanks for exposing my ignorance!

Comment: The key -- your error messages will tell you where your problems usually are. Don't ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

Should :

```
private ListNode<T> nextNode;
```

Be?:

```
private ListNode<T> node;
```